# file sharing between android devices without bluetooth and internet connection

Tags: wifi-direct

what if you dont have internet service on your android devices but still want to use the wifi to transfer files. I have found there are many ways to transfer files but they all use the browser and need it to get on line and bluetooth is not an option on my tablet which is android also

Answer (score 2):

I use ES file explorer.  It lets me access my home network disk drives via WiFi.

To test this, I opened my phone to the DCIM photo area, press/hold one file, "copy to" then navigated UP from the SD card, where it gave me my network connections (which I'd already browsed to with ES File Explorer).

I could then navigate down to a directory and say [OK] and the file went to my NAS

I was able to view it (or transfer it) on another machine just fine.

IF you want to use WiFi directly from android device to android device, then both need to be able to go into "Ad Hoc" mode which means something like "without a central WiFi router".  I doubt that's in the "settings" but there may be something in the app store.  (Sorry I refuse to use that new name Google gave the app store, as I am serious, not playing around).  haha.

Comment: In researching further, Wifi Direct is apparently not supported on Android, but the HW can do it and there are ways if you are into "Rooting" your android.

Comment: Nowadays Wifi Direct is supported. I think from Android 4.4 upwards. In the sense thatt you can pair devices like with bluetooth. Probably still need a compatible app to transfer files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at WiFi Direct and alike. There are several apps on the Playstore making use of this, like e.g.

- [SuperBeam | WiFi Direct Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam) (with a fall-back to "hotspot mode" in case of WiFi Direct problems: one device creates a hotspot, the other connects to it)
- [WiFiShare : Share Files Freely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiitd.muc.wifishare) states it *brings WiFi-Direct like functionality on lower version of Android, it also enables to send large size files to multiple people at a time* -- which I understand as it does not depend on WiFi Direct, but emulates it itself.
- [Fast File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.fastfiletransfer) utilizes WiFi tethering to achieve the same. The description states you could even send files to an iPh**e (censored ;) It plugs into the "Share" menu.
- [WiFi Shoot! WiFi Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.budius.WiFiShoot) uses WiFi direct

One of those should be fitting your needs :)

Comment: I'd add Airdroid to that list, as it is popular and doesn't require internet (just a LAN, like most wifi-direct apps).

Comment: @jiggunjer this site is not about "popular lists". I was just giving examples for WiFi Direct. And *Airdroid* doesn't even use WiFi Direct ;)